# server client iphone

Tags: iphone, dictionary, client, client-server

i am building a map project and i want to save my annotations to the web and download them anytime i want. What's the best way to do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a web service on your server, design a simple REST API and communicate with it from your iPhone app. If you want more details, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: i am a bit confused with all that xml, sqlite and plist. i am using core data in my app and can't figure out how to use that

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer. I used touchjson and it worked fine getting the data. Got a little problem though posting things to the db